# Why do different installations of sort sort punctuation differently?

Tags: sort, cygwin

I got a file with content like this:

```
----------- 
=========== 
-------- 
-=-=-=-=-=-
```

When I sort in a linux os, it comes like this:

```
$ sort 1.txt
=========== 
-=-=-=-=-=- 
-------- 
-----------
```

But when I sort in cygwin, it comes like this:

```
$ sort 1.txt 
-------- 
----------- 
-=-=-=-=-=- 
===========
```

I'm wondering why the result is not the same. 
I notice that the sort version in linux is 5.97, and in cygwin is 8.24. Or it's an encoding problem?

Comment: What is the result of `hexdump 1.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a locale issue, compare the output of `locale` in your two environments, and adjust the one where you want the output changed.

For example, on Linux (the `sort` version or OS shouldn't matter much):

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort t
--------
-----------
-=-=-=-=-=-
===========
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort t
===========
-=-=-=-=-=-
--------
-----------
```

Comment: how to check the locale in two environments?

Comment: `locale` is a command, just type it.